# Android alarmmanager synchronized

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronize

I am referring to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService_Service.html

There the runnable of the thread looks like this

```
Runnable mTask = new Runnable() 
{        
    public void run() 
    {  
        Log.v("service", "thread is running after 5 min");
        // Normally we would do some work here...  for our sample, we will           
        // just sleep for 30 seconds.            
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 15*1000;            
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) 
        {                
            synchronized (mBinder) 
            {                    
                try 
                {                        
                    mBinder.wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());      
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {                    

                }                
            }            
        }            // Done with our work...  stop the service!            
        AlarmService_Service.this.stopSelf();     
    }    
}
```

I admit that I have some problems with the concept of synchronized... The thread runs the while loop to wait 15s, within that loop I have wait for 15s. So how would the runnable look like if I just want to write a log entry e.g. Log.v(TAG,TEXT);? What would change if I want to write a new entry into my own database table?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a log statement then the following will work fine

```
Runnable mTask = new Runnable() 
{        
    public void run() 
    {  
        Log.v("TAG", "Some verbose log message");
    }    
}
```

Whether you need to use `synchronized` on an object depends on whether object is thread-safe or not. If it is not thread-safe, then you will need to ensure that only one thread access the object at a time by using a synchronized block. In your example `mBinder` is not thread-safe, so in order to call the `wait` method of the binder you need to ensure that you are the only thread accessing it.

A `runnable` is most often used to execute code in a different thread, so that long running operations (such as IO, but in this case just waiting) do not block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

try 
{
 mBinder.wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
} 
 catch (Exception e) 
{

}

...with the code you want to execute?

Synchronized is just to assert that only one process accesses the thread at one time.

Comment: yes and no, I have the outer while loop I don't need, then I have the code here inside the synchronized(mBinder). In the example above they do something with the mBinder object (calling wait). I wouldn't do anything with the mBinder object, would I? So do I need this synchronized?